# Как заставить новый процесс Process ждать завершения старого?

Tags: c#

Процессы запускаются поочерёдно. Но не могут выполниться тк. предыдущий не  завершён.

```
public static void RemoveProvisionedAppxPackage__Name()
            {
                string[] list_names =
                {
                    "Microsoft.3DBuilder_11.0.47.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe",
                    "Microsoft.BingWeather_4.9.51.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe"

                };
                foreach (var i in list_names)
                {
                    RemoveProvisionedAppxPackage__Name2(@"/Image:z:\_images\_mount /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage  /PackageName:" + i);
                };
            }
            public static void RemoveProvisionedAppxPackage__Name2(string name)
            {
                Process MyProc = new Process();
                MyProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"Dism.exe";
                MyProc.StartInfo.Arguments = name;
                MyProc.Start();
            }
```

Comment: Ну так не запускайте процесс, пока старый не завершится. В чём сложность?

Comment: они в цикле foreach

Comment: `MyProc.WaitForExit();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends

Comment: @codename0082016: Да, и что? Дожидайтесь окончания в цикле `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло........

```
MyProc.WaitForExit();
```